# SparkMap[RDD] - map toMany-One

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a rdd in the following form:

```
[ ("a") -> (pos3, pos5), ("b") -> (pos1, pos7), .... ]
```

and

```
(pos1 ,pos2, ............, posn)
```

Q: How can I map each position to its key ?(to be something like the following)

```
("b", "e", "a", "d", "a" .....) 
// "b" correspond to pos 1, "e" correspond to pose 2 and ...
```

Example(edit) :

```
// chunk of my data 
val data = Vector(("a",(124)), ("b",(125)), ("c",(121, 123)), ("d",(122)),..)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)


// from rdd I can create my position rdd which is something like: 
val positions = Vector(1,2,3,4,.......125) // my positions

// I want to map each position to my tokens("a", "b", "c", ....) to achive:
Vector("a", "b", "a", ...)
// a correspond to pos1, b correspond to pos2 ...
```

Comment: Hi @Sahand, can you please share your data structure ? (ie: Case class)

Comment: Could you please create an [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - Also, is your expected output an **RDD** / **DS** / **DF** or a normal **Scala** _collection_?

Comment: Seems like you're working with a Vector[(String, Any)] is that correct ? Your tuples don't have the same size. I'd recommend you to work with a Vector[(String, Set[Int])] instead.

Comment: thanx :) I try to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure you have to use Spark to address this specific use case (starting with a Vector, ending with a Vector containing all your data characters).

Nevertheless, here's some suggestion if it suits your needs :

```
val data = Vector(("a",Set(124)), ("b", Set(125)), ("c", Set(121, 123)), ("d", Set(122)))
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

val result = rdd.flatMap{case (k,positions) => positions.map(p => Map(p -> k))}
      .reduce(_ ++ _) //here, we aggregate the Map objects together, reducing partitions first and then merging executors results
      .toVector
      .sortBy(_._1) //We sort data based on position
      .map(_._2) // We only keep characters
      .mkString
```